# getting 'name' is an invalid keyword argument (using graphene-django)

Tags: django, graphene-django

i am using graphene and getting 'name' is an invalid keyword argument for GuestMutation error what is it related to?

```python
//models.py

class Guest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



//schema.py
class GuestType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Guest
        fields = ('id','name','phone')
        
        
class GuestMutation (graphene.Mutation):

    class Arguments:
        name = graphene.String(required=True)
        phone = graphene.Int(required=True)

    guest = graphene.Field(GuestType)

    @classmethod
    def mutate(cls, root,info,name,phone):
        guest = Guest(name=name, phone=phone)
        guest.save()
        return GuestMutation(name=name, phone=phone)

class Mutation(graphene.ObjectType):

    add_guest = GuestMutation.Field()
```

error message

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ahmed/Documents/Django/Shalleh/my-project-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/promise/promise.py", line 489, in _resolve_from_executor
executor(resolve, reject)
File "/home/ahmed/Documents/Django/Shalleh/my-project-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/promise/promise.py", line 756, in executor
return resolve(f(*args, **kwargs))
File "/home/ahmed/Documents/Django/Shalleh/my-project-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphql/execution/middleware.py", line 75, in make_it_promise
return next(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ahmed/Documents/Django/Shalleh/booking/schema.py", line 66, in mutate
return GuestMutation(name=name, phone=phone)
File "/home/ahmed/Documents/Django/Shalleh/my-project-env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/graphene/types/objecttype.py", line 169, in **init**
raise TypeError(
graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: 'name' is an invalid keyword argument for GuestMutation

Comment: Try to `return GuestMutation(guest=guest)`

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the wrong information:

```py
class GuestMutation (graphene.Mutation):
    # What you accept as input
    class Arguments:
        name = graphene.String(required=True)
        phone = graphene.Int(required=True)

    # What you return as output
    guest = graphene.Field(GuestType)
```

So as mentioned, you need to return the guest you created.